# Which corpus should I download to access nltk.corpus.words?

Tags: python, nltk

My code references `nltk.corpus.words.words()`.

Which [NLTK data](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) set to I need to download to access it?

Right now I'm telling the downloader to download all data sets by doing `python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all`. I don't need all data sets, though, I just the one that provides `nltk.corpus.words.words()`.

My question is: what should I replace `all` with in the downloader command above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should be the one

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using. I need to know which [data set](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) to download before I can use this.

Comment: in your link, 84. is 'words'. do: import nltk then nltk.download('words')

Comment: @gawju thanks, that worked. (it would probably be more helpful as a part of the original answer)

Comment: happy to help :)